# The receiver moved his foot as I was serving in badminton. Is it legal?

Tags: rules, badminton, serve

There are always a lot of mind games around the service procedure in badminton. Last week I played a guy who twitched his foot every time I was serving. I found this very distracting at the critical point of the stroke. Is that legal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Laws of Badminton](http://www.bwfbadminton.org/file.aspx?id=608602&dl=1), 9.1.3:

> Some part of both feet of the server and the receiver must remain in contact with the surface of the court in a stationary position from the start of the service (Law 9.2) until the service is delivered (Law 9.3).

It's unclear what you mean about twitching his foot, but it sounds like it might be legal and might not be depending on the particular action of the foot.

Comment: Agreed, it's a grey area. I think the player was close to committing a fault, because there's also a rule against distracting your opponent. My solution was to hold the serve a little bit longer, making the guy's antics more obvious (and he lost his balance sometimes). But it was hard to convince him that moving before the serve is a fault!